# Trying to animate text-transform and text-decoration. Works everywhere except Safari (bot mobile and desktop)

Tags: css, animation, safari

Okay this works everywhere(Chromium, FF) except safari. For some reason text-transform and text-decoration is being ignored while the rest works just fine.

I know I can add -webkit prefixes but that does not change anything besides I'm targeting 2 latest versions anyway so prefix is not needed.

Any ideas?

I've searched all over the net with no avail.

```css
a[href^="mailto"] {
  color: black;
}
a[href^="mailto"]:hover,
a[href^="mailto"]:hover * {
    color: black !important;
    border: none !important;
    animation: glitch 4s infinite steps(50);
}



@keyframes glitch {
    2% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: line-through;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    4% {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    6% {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    8% {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    10% {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    12% {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    14% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: line-through;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    16% {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    18% {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    20% {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    22% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    24% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    26% {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: line-through;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    28% {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: line-through;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    30% {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: line-through;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    32% {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    34% {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    36% {
        font-weight: 100;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    38% {
        font-weight: 100;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    40% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    42% {
        font-weight: 100;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    44% {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: line-through;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    46% {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    48% {
        font-weight: 100;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    50% {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    52% {
        font-weight: 100;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    54% {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    56% {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    58% {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    60% {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    62% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    64% {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: line-through;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    66% {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    68% {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    70% {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    72% {
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    74% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    76% {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    78% {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    80% {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    82% {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    84% {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    86% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    88% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    90% {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
    92% {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    94% {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-style: italic;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    96% {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    98% {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:someone@mail.com?subject=Hello" id="hello">someone@mail.com</a>
```